# Execute a callback method from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, callback

I've created a view that installs an alarm via AlarmManager, which will in turn execute a BroadcastReceiver subtype specified by me.

In this BroadcastReceiver, I would like to call a method of my view: I need to clean up after the alarm happened. Can I somehow call my view from the BroadcastReceiver?

I've tried to solve the issue by turning my BroadcastReceiver into an inner class, but I couldn't make it work with Context.registerReceiver(), plus I'd rather have it as a top level type for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I somehow call my view from the BroadcastReceiver?

Probably not. Usually `AlarmManager` alarms invoke receivers registered in the manifest. Those receivers exist on their own, independent from any other Android components.

You can register a receiver via `registerReceiver()` from your activity, and that receiver could access a `View` in the activity, and you could possibly target that receiver with `AlarmManager`, but that will only work while the activity is in the foreground.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this works. However, I've thought this through again and found a better way. Callback from an AlarmManager to UI are a really bad idea, eh?

Comment: @Jason Noack: "Callback from an AlarmManager to UI are a really bad idea, eh?" I'm not quite sure what this means, and I have no idea what sort of app you're building.   You might wish to check out this blog post of mine, which describes one pattern for dealing with problems in this area that might fit your needs: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html